# How to add click event and write text to a flowpanel

Tags: c#, arrays, events, button, click

I have this method which creates buttons :

```
        Button[] CreatingButtons(int n, List<string> names)
    {
        Button[] Buttons = new Button[n];
        int horizontal = 180; int vertical = 5;
        int Height = 33; int Width = 350 / Buttons.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            Buttons[i] = new Button();
            Buttons[i].Height = Height;
            Buttons[i].Width = Width;
            this.Controls.Add(Buttons[i]);
            Buttons[i].Text = names[i];
            Buttons[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            Buttons[i].Location = new Point(horizontal, vertical);
            horizontal += Buttons[i].Width;
            Buttons[i].Click += (o, k) => 
            {

            };
        }
        return Buttons;
    }
```

As you can see the click event is empty still. I also have `FlowDirectionPanel` which is called `textPanel`.

I need the click event to show some text in this panel and also some images every button will show different things. How can i do this ? I have never worked before with panels

Comment: where you want to show some text and how you want to show based on every button click ?

Comment: i want to show the text in the flowdirectionpanel called textPanel every button will show different things

Comment: and is there any things in your buttons array which can differentiate each button

Comment: well im creating 4 different array of buttons with this function right here so yes there is

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you really want to show in your panel but you can just place a `TextBox` an a `PictureBox` to the panel and change their `Text` and `Image` properties.

```
List<string> textValues=new List<string> {"A","B",...}; //Add your different values to the list
List<Image> imgValues=new List<string> {image1,image2,...}; //Add your different images to the list

Buttons[i].Click += (o, k) => 
            {
              textBox1.Text= textValues[i];
              pictureBox1.Image= imgValues[i];
            };
```

Comment: i think i should add these as childrens of the panel

Comment: op wants to show different things on each button don't you think every button should generate same things usng your code except i

Answer (score 0):

As per comments you are creating four different array of buttons so it's better to use the class and properties instead of array of buttons like

you have to declare one class like

```
 internal class ButtonsDetails
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Image imgsource { get; set; }
    }
```

and your button generation method should be

```
private static void GenerateButton(List<ButtonsDetails> details)
        {
            foreach (var item in details)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Click += (o, k) =>
                {
                    textBox1.Text = item.Text
                    pictureBox1.Image = item.imgsource
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: well the first array have let's say 3 buttons and all of them will have a different things to show

Comment: then array of button should not work you have to declare one class in that you have to declare properties and and create a collection of that class and used it

Comment: @QuestionsEverywhere:let me know proper what you exactly want to do with it so I can create example for you

Comment: i use the method in my question to create 4 different arrays with 3 buttons each and each button have a different text and image to show in the flowdirectionpanel

Comment: @QuestionsEverywhere: you mean the names of button present in List<string> names ?

Comment: Button [] arraynumber1
{
button1 contains text="ASD", image = "smily face"
button 2 contains text = "asD", image = "sad face"
}
Button [] arraynumber2
{
button1 contains text="qwe", image = "drunk"
button 2 contains text = "ewq", image = "sleepy"
}
each of my 4 arrays has his own buttons and they will all print text and images to the panel but just a different ones

Comment: how do i add the images and the text now ? i mean how do i insert them in the internal class ? and also this will not work since i make the 4 arrays in a different time and this will insert 12 images 12 text's into array with just 3  items in it